# Microsoft Graph API /me/people 403 forbidden error

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting 403 Forbidden error while trying to use /me/people to get a list of contacts on Outlook. This is working on Graph Explore, but not in my application.

```js
try {
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${req.user.accessToken}`,
    },
  });
  res.send(response.data);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the token that you're using doesn't have enough permissions. According to the documentation for `GET /v1.0/me/people` at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http you need `People.Read` or `People.Read.All`. Can you confirm you have those in the access token?
What this means is when users login to your application with their Microsoft account they'll be prompted to give your app access to their contacts. If you're writing an app that runs without user interaction (background process) you should follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) for authorizing your application.